# upgrade a revised module using GIT

Tags: git, version-control, code-reuse

I used an open source library in my project. But according to my requirements, I changed many parts of the open source library code.
Now, there is a new version of the opensource library, and I wanted to merge the changes that I did to the new version of the open source library.

Since I may need to make more changes to the source code and there will be next versions of the library, I think is better to have a semi-automatic way to marge.

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: I would say Not yet! both answers are correct but still not the automatic way that I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mean you wan to solve the conflict automatically? I added this part in my answer.

Comment: maybe automatically is very ambitious. But at lease I wanted a more structured way.

Comment: If you want to explore other ways, you can try to use **git hooks**, such as post merge/post commit hooks. Or you can execute a **script** to trigger git commands. But use git command directly is the frequent way for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can clone git repo locally and make your changes.

When you are ready to merge your changes with the new version of open source library, you can follow these steps (assume you are working on `master` branch):

```
# on master branch
git pull origin master --rebase
# If there have conflict files, you can modify/save the files, then use `git add .` and `git rebase --continue`
git push origin master
```

To solve the conflict files automatically, you can use `-X` option:

`git pull origin master --rebase -X theirs`, solve the conflict file by keeping your local `master` version.

`git pull origin master --rebase -X ours`, solve the conflict file by keeping `origin/master` version.

Answer (score 1):

As many before you, you have discovered that while creating a fork is easy, *maintaining* a fork can be a lot of work.

So consider contributing your changes back to the original ("upstream") project.

Every change that is accepted upstream is one you will *never* have to merge again...

Answer (score 0):

You should have a fork of the project and work on your own branch.
Once a new version is releases you will be able (after resolve conflicts if any) merge it into your account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Actually this is the way that I use now. Although, it is very accurate but has many manual works to do.